# Trying to update robots.txt

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I have installed and activaded the WP Robots txt plugin. Then I have gone to `wp-admin/options-reading.php` I have pasted a new robotst.txt content and Save it. But I can not see the new content at  `mysite.com/robots.txt` Any help? I have installed also the SEO plugins, could be this related?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support routes available from the plugin developer. That being said, it looks like the WP Robots Txt plugin hasn't been updated in a while and others have posted similar issues in the plugin's support forum. Check if the SEO plugin you're using has the option to edit robots.txt. I use Wordpress SEO by Yoast (no affiliation) and it has the option to edit robots.txt or .htaccess under Edit Files, which I just discovered. Or, the issue might just be that your robots.txt isn't writable from WP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an actual `robots.txt` file in the root of your site then WP/plugins will be unable to override it. Its related functionality works with "virtual" file, when actual file doesn't exist.

Otherwise it might be plugin conflict, try one related plugin at a time.